# unescaping html entities which are encoded like \u0

Tags: java

I am facing a problem that my html entities which look like `\u00 ...` are displayed as it is in browser. Is there a way to decode them?

Comment: Have a look at `URLDecoder.decode(String, String)` or maybe I didn't understand exactly what's your problem.

Comment: `\uNNNN` isn't an "HTML entity", it's the way you escape Unicode characters in a JavaScript string literal. You probably need to find the code that is producing these strings in the first place and modify it to encode the characters as HTML character references instead of JS escapes.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the StringEscapeUtils available in the commons-lang-2.3.jar
The method is StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(String). Also the StringEscapeUtils  contains api for escaping or unescaping various formats like xml javascript sql etc.

Thanks